# Align text to be centered vertically in a container? twitter-bootstrap-3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Is it possible to use the CSS to align text as centered vertically in a container in twitter bootstrap 3?

Comment: This is your second question that really shows no effort on your part... Please review http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking a question. First step, do some research. Next, try to solve the issue. Finally, if you're stuck, ask a question here and we should be able to help.

Comment: ....while showing what you've tried.

Comment: I have googled extensively to try to find a simple answer to this question and have not found it.  Instead of reinventing the wheel I hoped someone intelligent would have already resolved this and been willing to share.

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS to the element containing the text (NOT to an element with a col class--add to the element within it):

```
.v-center{
    display:block;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple center class in CSS

```
   .center-element {
        min-height: 100%;
        min-height: 50vh;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
```